# Gem stream-rails : Gem installed successfully, but no functionality

Tags: ruby-on-rails

just started to use stream-rails. I've tried to install stream-rails gem both from the terminal and on my gen file. It says that the gem is installed but the "config/initializers/stream_rails.rb" has not been created. Please advise.
Fred

Comment: What version of rails are you using?

Answer (score 0):

welcome to StackOverflow!

As described in [setup instructions over here](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-rails#setup), you need to add that file. It'll not be auto-generated.

Have a look at setup-instructions -

```
Login with Github on getstream.io and get your api_key and api_secret from your app configuration (Dashboard screen).

Then you can add the StreamRails configuration in config/initializers/stream_rails.rb
```